# NSURLConnection: Confusion with the oder in which connection:didReceiveResponse: and connection:didFailWithError: are called

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

This may be a very silly question!! But, as I am having a doubt, thought of asking here.

1. Are the two delegate methods (i.e. `connection:didReceiveResponse:` and `connection:didFailWithError:`) are mutually exclusive to each other? I mean is there any scenario in which both the delegate methods could get called by NSURLConnection object?
2. In case only `connection:didFailWithError:` gets called, how to retrieve the HTTP status code?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> The only case where this message is not sent to the delegate is when
>   the protocol implementation encounters an error before a response
>   could be created.

[NSURLConnectionDelegate Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:didFailWithError:)

So, a NSURLConnection could fail before it gets a response, however it could fail after. Since connection:didFailWithError ceases any further messages for that connection, the following two scenarios could happen:

1. The connection is started, fails to get a response and connection:didFailWithError is called.
2. The connection is started and gets a response, connection:didReceiveResponse: is called, then the connection fails for some reason (The network connection could drop out for example), before connectionDidFinishLoading is called.

You will need to get the HTTP status code from connection:didReceiveResponse, if that method isn't called, there is no status code as it is part of the response. If you need to access it from within connection:didFailWithError you will need to record it.

Note that to get the status code, you will also need to case NSURLResponse to NSHTTPURLResponse like so:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
NSLog(@"Status code %ld", httpResponse.statusCode);
```

Comment: So, when connection: didReceiveResponse: is called, it can either end up in connection: didFinishLoading: or connection: didFailWithError: ?

Comment: If it's successful, it'll call didReceiveData: where you need to record the data (easiest way is to used appendData on an NSMutableData object) before calling didFinishLoading: if it's successful. If it fails it may still call didReceiveData before failing (as the connection could fail at any point). But yes, the connection should either end up calling either connection:didFinishLoading or connection:didFailWithError:

Comment: Sorry for late reply!! How to capture network errors like 400, 404, 500 etc. Do they get notified in connection: didReceiveResponse: or connection: didFailWithError: ?

Comment: Basically, I want to know how to handle all kinds of error scenarios without missing something. Can I get all the errors in connection: didFailWithError: or I need to depend on connection: didReceiveResponse: also? This will be helpful!!

Comment: They get notified in connection:didRecieveResponse. Those errors are status codes from the server and form part of the servers response.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am getting into it slowly. So, in case of those errors ( 400, 404, 500 etc), first connection: didReceiveResponse: will be called as you said. After that, which method will be called. It's connection: didFinishLoading: or connection: didFailWithError: ?

Comment: IIRC, you'll get didFinishLoading unless the connection is terminated early (e.g. by a network failure).  A server's response code indicates a server-side error, whereas didFailWithError typically indicates a communication error or library error.  Each of those error responses also contains a body (often just the word "forbidden", but it could just as easily be a full web page with explanatory text).  So when you get one of those error codes, the request really does complete successfully; it just doesn't provide you with the data you were expecting.

Comment: As a rule, if you care about the error page body, go ahead and let the request continue to fetch data.  Otherwise, you should cancel the request in your didReceiveResponse: method.  If you do so, you won't get any more callbacks for that request.